# How do you create a probabilistic conditional flow in python?

Tags: python

I'm thinking of a conditional flow that roughly produces a float half the time, or an integer half a time. My code is this:

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    binarychoice=random.randint(0,1)
    if binarychoice=0:
        pass #do whatever you need to do, return an integer
    elif binarychoice=1:
        pass #do whatever you need, return a float
```

Is this correct? However, are there any libraries available to do such a probabilistic conditional flow (because I've never really heard of it, largely due to inexperience), such that I can simply write  something along the line of "X...or Y" and the probability of executing X or Y is half?

Comment: `binarychoice==0` instead of `binarychoice=0` and `binarychoice==1` instead of `binarychoice=1`

Comment: Are you looking for uniform random or are you looking to weight you randomness somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just 50/50, this is a bit cleaner:

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    if random.randint(0,1):
        pass #do whatever you need to do, return an integer
    else:
        pass #do whatever you need, return a float
```

Or for more flexibility with the probability:

```
import random
for i in range(10):
    if random.random() < .8:
        pass #do whatever you need to do, return an integer
    else:
        pass #do whatever you need, return a float
```